# Print JSON data as a table in HTML

Tags: html, json

How can I print the following JSON data as a HTML table:

```
{"response":
{"tweets":
    [{"ID":"718045120386441216","TDate":"Thu Apr 07 11:57:51 +0000 2016",
    "FormerPlace":
        {"id":"07e9c7d1954fff64","url":"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/07e9c7d1954fff64.json","place_type":"city","name":"Sheffield","full_name":"Sheffield, England","country_code":"GB","country":"United Kingdom","contained_within":[],"bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-1.573648,53.309898],[-1.325576,53.309898],[-1.325576,53.4564311],[-1.573648,53.4564311]]]},"attributes":{}},
        "Label":"@brain4_digital Let us go to #Italy @abdulazizDhafer",
        "InReplyTo":
            {"ID":"699983775007170560","ScreenName":"brain4_digital","UserID":"4909086905"},
        "UserMentions":
            [{"ID":"4909086905","ScreenName":"brain4_digital","Name":"Digital Brain"},{"ID":"305152994","ScreenName":"abdulazizDhafer","Name":"عبدالعزيز العمري"}],
        "Hashtags":["Italy"],
        "User":
            {"ID":"707943702623338497","ScreenName":"NasserPshko","Name":"Nasser","Location":"","Link":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/707951652515532800/N-bWyjg9_normal.jpg"}
    }],
"stats":
    {"topUsers":[{"user":"NasserPshko","count":1,"topWords":[{"word":"@brain4_digital","count":1},{"word":"Let","count":1},{"word":"us","count":1},{"word":"go","count":1},{"word":"#Italy","count":1}]}],"topWords":[{"word":"@brain4_digital","count":1},{"word":"Let","count":1},{"word":"us","count":1},{"word":"go","count":1},{"word":"#Italy","count":1},{"word":"@abdulazizDhafer","count":1}]}}}
```

First, I have tried to print out each element in JSON as:

```
var arr=JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            for (var i in arr){
                alert(arr.response[i].tweets);
            }
```

and it didn't work. Is there any other ways to print each JSON value separately?

Comment: First of all, it would be better to use console.log() instead of alert() [less disturbing]. Do you know how to work with console.log?

Comment: @IsraGab Thanks I have tried in your way but still it did not work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You have a problem with your loop. But I wanted you to use console.log(), because now you should be able to see the prints on your console.

Comment: Do the loop work at all? If you log `arr` before entering the loop, what's the result?

Answer (score 0):

Could not wrap my head around what you actually was looking for, so I made some examples of how you can work with that particular JSON document.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(arr);

/** Navigating inside the response, selecting the tweets **/
var tweets = arr.response.tweets;
console.log(arr.response.tweets);

/** Looping through the different properties of a tweet **/
for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){
  console.log(tweets[i]);

  /** Here you can set a property to some HTML element. I.e. the date **/
  console.log(tweets[i].TDate);
}
```

First things first: Parse the response as JSON, that you already managed. Then you have to navigate through the parsed json using dot-notation (i.e. `someProperty.somePropertyOnAnotherLevel`).

Then at last we come to what I guess is part of your problem: Iterating the properties on different levels: Using a standard `for-loop` iterating through all it's properties.